# Is there any way I can make the connection bar "more difficult" to display using the Microsoft Terminal Services Client?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, terminal-services

The Microsoft Terminal Services Client (Also known as "Remote Desktop" or RDP) is an awesome remote access tool that I use all the time. It has but one major annoyance -- there's a bar at the top of any full screen window which is used to control the remote session itself. I understand the need for such a bar (to do things like minimize the `mstsc` session itself), but it would be better if instead of auto-hide, it would simply only show when I press a certain keyboard shortcut or something like that.

I'm open to looking at third party clients if they would be able to make that frustrating connection bar go away :)

(Specifically, it screws things up when I'm using Google Chrome inside an RDP session, because putting my pointer where the tabs are causes the connection bar to appear and block me, and it also causes problems if I use the Areo Snap feature to maximize the current window in Windows 7 guests)

Comment: if you edit the connection and go to the Display tab and uncheck "Display the connection bar when in full screen mode" does that fix the problem?

Comment: @Xantec: 1. Yes, can you put that in an answer (so I can upvote/possibly checkmark it)? 2. How does one get out of the session (i.e. minimize the RDP window) without **any** way of getting the connection bar?

Comment: placed in answer

Comment: Exact same problem here.  But for me, I'd prefer just to make it auto-hide much faster (ideally, immediately when the mouse moves off it).  Plus this has the advantage that the auto-hide delay is surely an existing setting specified *somewhere* (though- worst case scenario, it could be hard-coded). CTRL-ALT-*XXX* shortcuts are all good, but they're hard to use one-handed, e.g. when your other hand is holding food, or a phone, etc. and you're basically doing everything with the mouse.  (A frequent situation for me).  Does anyone know how to change the auto-hide timing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit the connection and go to the Display tab and uncheck "Display the connection bar when in full screen mode".

To get out of the remote desktop and back to your desktop use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>. This will window the RDC.

To go back to full screen use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> again.

Comment: Old answer but wanted to throw my thanks out anyway. Wish I would've known about this sooner, that bar is a major PIA and always getting in the way. Thanks!