# Is there a way to change the delay before the windows remote desktop menu pops up when unpinned?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way I can make the connection bar “more difficult” to display using the Microsoft Terminal Services Client?](https://superuser.com/questions/214233/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-the-connection-bar-more-difficult-to-display-using)

I'm talking about the blue bar at the top with the minimize/restore/close button.

You can unpin it which is great, but I was wondering if there's a way to change it so it wait say 5 seconds before popping up because it gets in the way of selecting tabs in Chrome.

Edit: Looks like this is a dupe of [Is there any way I can make the connection bar “more difficult” to display using the Microsoft Terminal Services Client?](https://superuser.com/questions/214233/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-the-connection-bar-more-difficult-to-display-using) which I did not find before.  I don't have enough rep to close as dupe, but this should be closed as such.

Comment: Definitely not an answer to your question, but you could always use ctrl+shift to scroll through your tabs if an answer is not found.

Comment: @gtaylor yeah, I can also slide the bar over the the other side.  I average around 20-40 tabs open at a time so it takes a while to tab through.

Comment: Another quick thing I found. You can turn it off altogether, but I didn't see any options for delaying it. Turn it off Remote Desktop Options > Display > "Display connection bar in full-screen." Might not be useful if you minimize a lot.

Comment: @gtaylor that lead me to finding this question http://superuser.com/questions/214233/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-the-connection-bar-more-difficult-to-display-using which suggested doing exactly that and additionally that Ctrl-Alt-Break will switch it to windowed mode.

Comment: What about, rather than trying to  delay its *appearance*, you simply make it auto-hide much quicker?  So you can get rid of it fast with just a small mouse movement, without waiting 5 or 10 seconds (whatever the setting is).  Personally I think that would actually work better than a *delay*, but also it has the advantage that the auto-hide time has to be in an existing setting somewhere (though it might be hard-coded into the software), whereas an appearance delay is probably an entirely new, not-currently-supported feature.